# What to do if Installation in virtual machine says "no detected operating systems"?

Tags: installation, virtualization

I'm installing Ubuntu 12.10 in a virtual machine using Virtualbox with Windows 7 as the host OS.

One of the steps is to follow the regular installation procedure, but then I encountered a problem that says that there is no current OS in my computer. The choices that I have are to erase disk or to create a partition. I'm not sure what to do next.

A screenshot of the installation step concerned is below:

[image]

Comment: A screenshot would help here.

Comment: I'm really sorry to ask you this.. I already have the picture but I really don't know how to post the image here. May I ask you how?

Comment: http://imgur.com/ and post the link here

Comment: here's the link: http://imgur.com/0qAUB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VirtualBox will create a file drive inside your Windows file system that emulates a disk by itself.

It is not (unless specified) using a real hard disk. Since that virtual disk is empty, the Ubuntu installation inside the vbox will give you only the option to initialize and create a new partition.

You should not worry about modifications actually happening to your hard disk, the only thing affected will be the virtual drive you just created when adding a new vbox, it is safe to press next and create new partitions.

Comment: ohh. so it is actually referring to the virtual disk not to the hard disk. ok. thanks for your help. I'm going to proceed with the installation then :)